# filtering an object for ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have an object of this form:

$scope.cars = {"honda" : {label : "Honda", isDisplayed : true}, "toyota" : {label : "Toyota", isDisplayed : false}}.

I want to display the "label" in a dropdown where the "isDisplayed" property is true. What is the filter expression for this? The following does not work:

`<selected ng-model="car.selected" ng-options="value as value.label for (key,value) in cars | filter:{isDisplayed:true}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Filter works on an array not a object map. Change your `cars` object to an array, which makes more sense

```
$scope.cars = [ {label : "Honda", isDisplayed : true},  {label : "Toyota", isDisplayed : false}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Works fine when its an array.

Comment: This is the best way.  You could list the properties but you would end up creating an array anyway to get the property names.